# Scatter plot with colors and legends

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am having a hard time trying to create a scatter plot that will show points of different classes with different colors and the corresponding label of the class in the legend.

I have 52 samples, 2 features and 3 classes(class 1,2 and 3). The data are in `X` array and the labels in `labels` array.

I want to plot the legend that will contain the class names (1,2 and 3) for the corresponding colors.

---

**My code**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(52,2)

labels = np.ones(x.shape[0])
labels[0:8] = 1
labels[8:31] = 2 
labels[31:] = 3

plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c = labels, label = labels)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

---

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to plot your classes separately:

```
x = np.random.rand(52,2)

labels = np.ones(x.shape[0])
labels[0:8] = 1
labels[8:31] = 2 
labels[31:] = 3


for i in np.unique(labels):
    plt.scatter(x[np.where(labels==i),0], x[np.where(labels==i),1], label=i)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. I am coming back with a new question. Can i do the same but this time using seaborn's sns.jointplot function ?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

> **3. Explicitly defining the elements in the legend**
>
> For full control of which artists have a legend entry, it is possible
>   to pass an iterable of legend artists followed by an iterable of
>   legend labels respectively:
>
> ```
> legend((line1, line2, line3), ('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
> ```